# Cards in a split screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

I'm trying to build product cards into a split screen but they continue to stack on top of each other instead of side-by-side.

Does anyone have a solution ?

My code can be found below. I'm a newbie at coding, so ignore the some of the images and lack of experience. The purpose of this code is to create a uniform display of items being auction offed for charity.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stuf Auction</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stufcss.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- left side -->
    <div class="split left">
        <div class="centered">
            <img src="images/stufgreen.png" alt="stuf logo">
            <h2></h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- right side -->
    <div class="split right">
        <div class="centered">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-content">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="images/jordanshoes.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
                    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
                    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
                    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
                    <p><button>Bid</button></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="images/jordanshoes.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
                    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
                    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
                    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
                    <p><button>Bid</button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- footer -->
    <footer class="site footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-5 text-center">
                    <h5>Social</h5>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-instagram" href="http://instagram.com/"><i
                            class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/"><i
                            class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-link" href="tel:+12065551234"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        1-206-555-1234</a><br />
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:campsites@nucamp.co"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        campsites@nucamp.co</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some example code

Comment: At least post the html you are using for the cards.  if you want 2 cards per row using 50% of the row each, you will want to add the class `.col-md-6` to the containing `div` of each card.

Comment: code added above.

Answer (score 0):

There's no class as `split` in bootstrap-4. If you want to split your screen you can use bootstrap-grids

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One column
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[more info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)